# Efficiently "drilling down" into XML tree with xlinq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm writing a program to parse some third-party XML files. The structure is something like...

```
<CharacterSheet>
    ...
    <StatBlock>
        ...
        <Stat>
            ...
            <alias />
            ...
        </Stat>
        ...
    </StatBlock>
    ...
</CharacterSheet>
```

I'm using this in to get some practice with linq, and I'm fining I have to write some really ugly chained queries to get what I want, a list of stats and all their alias.

```
var CharSheet = from i in character.Elements()
        where i.Name == "CharacterSheet"
        select i;

var StatBlocks = from sheet in CharSheet
         from statBlock in sheet.Elements()
         where statBlock.Name == "StatBlock"
         select statBlock;

var stats = from statBlock in StatBlocks
        from stat in statBlock.Elements()
        select stat;

var statAliases = from stat in stats
          from alias in stat.Elements()
          where alias.Name == "alias"
          select new { stat, alias };
```

And I realize I could make that into one really long query using "into" (which is originally how I had it), but that just made it even more dense and difficult to work with.

It seems like there's got to be a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`XPathSelectElements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) (which might be a better idea, to be honest), or you could use the [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784.aspx) extension method:

```
var query = character.Elements("CharacterSheet")
                     .Elements("StatsBlock")
                     .Elements()
                     .Elements("alias")
                     .Select(x => new { stat=x.Parent, alias=x};
```

Comment: Thanks! That was actually my natural inclination (trying .Elements("name"), but in visual studio it was saying that the only argument I could pass was an XName, so I didn't even try to use a string and I couldn't figure out how to make an XName.

But yeah, that works perfectly (or, at least, the compiler doesn't mind me putting strings there... I haven't tested it yet, but I suspect it should be fine).

Thanks!

Comment: Yup, you're using the implicit conversion from string to XName, which is used almost universally :)

Comment: The XName thing is a bit of a pain as the "intellisense" isn't intelligent enough to point developers that strings are implicitly converted.